# 1st Party Cookie not tracking in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I was trying setup GTM code for 1st Party Cookie in my website. But its not showing any value.

[1st Party Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC3wa.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You do not give much information, so this is a bit speculative. But one typical problem is that a first party cookie is set by the server with the "http only" flag, which means Javascript cannot interact with the cookie (for a short bit of history, the original function of cookies was to maintain state between http requests, which required them to be send as a part of the request, but does not require that they be readable by external scripts. Adding the http only flag is a security measure to prevent third party scripts from obtaining the cookie value, which is a problem if you require the value in GTM).